# Unable to open asset URL (Ionic Capacitor)

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

Hey my Ionic app runs with ionic serve without any issues on localhost. But when I try to test my app on an real Device with Android Studio it shows the splash screen but then only an white screen.
With Chrome inspector i get these errors:

> /runtime-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
> /polyfills-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
> /styles-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
> /vendor-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
> /main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
> /assets/icon/favicon.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)

Comment: Did you run `ionic build --prod --source-map && npx cap copy` before you run in Android Studio?

Comment: Thanks! ionic build --prod --source-map did it for me

Comment: Great to hear. I added it as an answer I would appreciate if you accept as answer and +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you run app in android studio you need to compile it. Run

```
ionic build --prod --source-map 
npx cap copy
```

So it compiles and sync those files